# How to query entries that exist in one table and not the other using PHP/mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want to query only the entries in table2 which contains a "course" value and "course" does not exist in table1. I initially inner joined table1 to table2 based on the "course" value. Here's what I have so far, which doesn't work:

```
    $query = "SELECT value1,value2,value3 FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 USING(course)
            WHERE table2.sem = '$semester' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT course FROM table1)
            ORDER BY course";
    $result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        print_r($row);echo "<br><br>";
    }
```

This inner join code works:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING(course) 
            WHERE table1.sem = '$semester'
            ORDER BY course";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE fk NOT IN (SELECT pk FROM foreign_table)`.

Comment: If you do a LEFT JOIN on table1 and the entry doesn't exist in table1, then its data will be set to NULL, so you can do a check for table1.data IS NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT value1,value2,value3 FROM table2 
            WHERE table2.sem = '$semester' AND course IS NOT NULL
            AND course NOT IN(SELECT course FROM table1)
            ORDER BY course";
```

EDIT:  If you want an in depth explanation as to why to go this route instead of the left join (which will also work) check out this article:

http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: Is the explanation valid for MySQL?

Comment: +1 for the link to an excellent explanation. It was illuminating.

Comment: @Vatev: further on in that series there is an explanation of MySQL's behaviour: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/  Summary: 'LEFT JOIN' and 'NOT IN' are equally fast but use different query plans in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for that @dnagirl i get so wrapped up in SQL Server i forget that there are often meaningful differences.

Comment: You'd want to add `WHERE course IS NOT NULL` to the subquery from table1, to avoid returning any NULL values... absent a guarantee that table1.course can not be NULL. (Even with such a guarantee, I always include that anyway, as a reminder that I don't ever want a NULL in that list, and for consistency with other places where I don't have such a guarantee.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT value1,value2,value3 
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.course = t1.course
WHERE t1.course IS NULL
  AND t2.sem = '$semester'
ORDER BY course";
```